# passing params throught rails forms

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails 4 and have a subject and comment models.  Subject is a one to many relationship with comments.  I want a simple page that can add comments to many subjects on the same page.  So in my form I know how to submit a comment to create but I dont know how to find the right subject in my controller to add it to.  Any advice?

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
    if comment.save
      # The line below is incorrect, I dont know what to do
      Subject.find(params[:subject_id]).comments << comment
      redirect_to(:controller => 'static_pages', action: 'home')
    end
  end

  def new
  end

  private

  def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:text, :user_name)
  end

end
```

> ## StaticPages#home
>
> Find me in
>   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb
>
> ```
> <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
>   <div class="subjects <%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
>
>   <h1><%= subject.name %></h1>
>   <h3><%= subject.description %></h3>
>
>     <% subject.comments.each do |comment|%>
>         <div class="comment">
>         <h4><%= comment.user_name%></h4>
>         <%= comment.text  %>
>         </div>
>     <% end %>
>
>     <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
>         <%= f.label :user_name %>
>         <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
>
>         <%= f.label :text %>
>         <%= f.text_field :text %>
>
>         <%= f.submit('Create comment', subject_id: subject.id) %>
>     <% end %>
>
>
>   </div>
> <% end %>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to populate the `subject_id` attribute of your `@comment` form, like this:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :user_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_name %>

    <%= f.label :text %>
    <%= f.text_field :text %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :subject_id, value: subject.id %>

    <%= f.submit('Create comment', subject_id: subject.id) %>
<% end %>
```

This will populate the `subject_id` attribute of your new `Comment` object, which will essentially associate it through Rails' backend:

[image]

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def create
       @comment = Comment.new comment_params
       @comment.save
   end

   private

   def comment_params
       params.require(:comment).permit(:subject_id, :text, :user_name)
   end
end
```

--

**foreign_keys**

This works because of the Rails / relational database [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) structure

Every time you associate two objects with Rails, or another relational database system, you basically have a database column which links the two. This is called a `foreign_key`, and in your case, every `Comment` will have the `subject_id` foreign_key column, associating it with the relevant subject

So you may have many different forms using the same `@comment` variable - the trick is to populate the `foreign_key` for each one

Comment: I had to add  <%= f.hidden_field :subject_id, value: subject.id %>
 to get it to work but otherwise you are right.  I still dont understand how rails magically knows to associate the comment with that subject just be injecting the Subject id.

Comment: It's not magic - it's a database column called "subject_id". I'll update for you